# Report Viewer só funciona local

Tags: mysql, asp.net, reportviewer

Desenvolvi uma aplicação ASP.NET WEB FORM e utilizei o Report Viewer para geração de relatórios e o MySQL. Porém, ao subir a aplicação para a hospedagem (GoDaddy), o Report Viewer não funciona. 
Já tentei de tudo, acho que é a falta da instalação do MySQL Connector, pois ao desinstalar da máquina local, obtive o mesmo erro que está aparecendo na hospedagem.

Segue print do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por isso e conhece alguma solução ou alternativa ao Report Viewer? A hospedagem é compartilhada então não consigo acesso direto para instalar o Connector.

Comment: Você instalou na sua maquina o MySQL connector, correto!? Basta você ir na pasta de instalação raiz e pegar na Bin as DLL referente ao MySQL... Se não me engano é, Mysql.data.dll e mais uma, e ai você manda na pasta Bin do seu projeto para a hospedagem.

Comment: Verifique se o ReportViewer.rdlc foi publicado junto com o site. Caso não, clique com o botão direito sobre o mesmo em clique em 'Publish', ou simplesmente copie o mesmo diretamente para o local do seu site no servidor.

Comment: Obrigado pela respota pessoal.O rdlc foi publicado junto com o site (já havia corrigido isso) e o MySql.Data.dll também, assim como as dll do Report Viewer. Parece estar tudo correto e não sei mais o que tentar.